# maven: javaagent en fichero pom.xml

Tags: java, maven

Estoy trabajando con una aplicación desplegada en maven, en la que necesito modificar el fichero pom.xml, para hacer que use un archivo jar cuando se despliega la aplicación.

He duplicado y modificado un trozo de código de ese archivo donde se usa -javaagent, pero algo debo de estar haciendo mal porque lanza un error y, ni se activa el jar, ni arranca tomcat.

Como opción, he probado de copiar manualmente el archivo war en el directorio webapps de tomcat, pero a pesar de que arranca tomcat y se activa el jar, como la aplicación desplegada necesita acceso a una base de datos, no termina de funcionar en todos los casos.

Adjunto código del archivo pom.xml: el primer profile (deploywcontrast) es el original y el segundo es el modificado(deploywfortify). También adjunto una captura de pantalla con el error que da al intentar arrancar desde maven.

[image: Error al arrancar desde maven]

```
<profile>
        <id>deploywcontrast</id>
        <properties>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>ldap-server</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <ant target="run" antfile="${basedir}/src/config/build.xml">
                                        <reference torefid="maven.compile.classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                    </ant>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>database-server</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <ant target="databaseServer" antfile="${basedir}/src/config/build.xml">
                                        <reference torefid="maven.compile.classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                    </ant>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>database-init</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <ant target="databaseInit" antfile="${basedir}/src/config/build.xml">
                                        <reference torefid="maven.compile.classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                    </ant>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <timeout>300000</timeout>
                            <containerId>tomcat8x</containerId>
                            <zipUrlInstaller>
                                <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.21/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.21.zip</url>
                            </zipUrlInstaller>
                        </container>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.jvmargs>-XX:MaxPermSize=6G -Xms1G –Xmx8G</cargo.jvmargs>
                        </properties>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <copy>
                                    <file>${basedir}/src/config/local/server.xml</file>
                                    <tofile>conf/server.xml</tofile>
                                    <configfile>true</configfile>
                                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                                </copy>
                            </files>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.jvmargs>
                                    -Xmx4G
                                    -javaagent:${basedir}/tools/Contrast/contrast.jar
                                    -Dcontrast.dir=${basedir}/tools/Contrast/working
                                    -Dcontrast.log.daily=true
                                    -Dcontrast.level=debug
                                    -Dcontrast.noteamserver.enable=true
                                    -Dcontrast.teamserver.suppress=true
                                </cargo.jvmargs>
                                <cargo.servlet.port>8443</cargo.servlet.port>
                                <cargo.protocol>https</cargo.protocol>
                                <cargo.tomcat.connector.clientAuth>false</cargo.tomcat.connector.clientAuth>
                                <cargo.tomcat.connector.sslProtocol>TLS</cargo.tomcat.connector.sslProtocol>
                                <cargo.tomcat.connector.keystoreFile>../../../../.keystore</cargo.tomcat.connector.keystoreFile>
                                <cargo.tomcat.connector.keystorePass>changeit</cargo.tomcat.connector.keystorePass>
                                <cargo.tomcat.connector.keyAlias>tomcat</cargo.tomcat.connector.keyAlias>
                                <cargo.tomcat.httpSecure>true</cargo.tomcat.httpSecure>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

    <profile>
        <id>deploywfortify</id>
        <properties>
            <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>ldap-server</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <ant target="run" antfile="${basedir}/src/config/build.xml">
                                        <reference torefid="maven.compile.classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                    </ant>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>database-server</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <ant target="databaseServer" antfile="${basedir}/src/config/build.xml">
                                        <reference torefid="maven.compile.classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                    </ant>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>database-init</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <target>
                                    <ant target="databaseInit" antfile="${basedir}/src/config/build.xml">
                                        <reference torefid="maven.compile.classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath" />
                                    </ant>
                                </target>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <timeout>300000</timeout>
                            <containerId>tomcat8x</containerId>
                            <zipUrlInstaller>
                                <url>http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.21/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.21.zip</url>
                            </zipUrlInstaller>
                        </container>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.jvmargs>-XX:MaxPermSize=6G -Xms1G –Xmx8G</cargo.jvmargs>
                        </properties>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <copy>
                                    <file>${basedir}/src/config/remote/server.xml</file>
                                    <tofile>conf/server.xml</tofile>
                                    <configfile>true</configfile>
                                    <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                                </copy>
                            </files>
                            <properties>
                                <cargo.jvmargs>
                                    -Xmx4G
                                    -javaagent:${basedir}/tools/AppDefender/lib.latest/FortifyAgent.jar
                                    -Dfortify.dir=${basedir}/tools/AppDefender/
                                    -Dfortify.log.daily=true
                                    -Dfortify.level=debug
                                    -Dfortify.noteamserver.enable=true
                                    -Dfortify.teamserver.suppress=true
                                </cargo.jvmargs>
                                <cargo.servlet.port>8443</cargo.servlet.port>
                                <cargo.protocol>https</cargo.protocol>
                                <cargo.tomcat.connector.clientAuth>false</cargo.tomcat.connector.clientAuth>
                                <cargo.tomcat.connector.sslProtocol>TLS</cargo.tomcat.connector.sslProtocol>
                                <cargo.tomcat.connector.keystoreFile>../../../../.keystore</cargo.tomcat.connector.keystoreFile>
                                <cargo.tomcat.connector.keystorePass>changeit</cargo.tomcat.connector.keystorePass>
                                <cargo.tomcat.connector.keyAlias>tomcat</cargo.tomcat.connector.keyAlias>
                                <cargo.tomcat.httpSecure>true</cargo.tomcat.httpSecure>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: Estás mostrando dos perfiles. ¿Cuál se ejecuta bien y cuál es el que te brinda los problemas? ¿Qué mensaje de error aparece cuando dices que "falla"?

Comment: El perfil que da problemas es el segundo (deploywfortify). El mensaje de error es el que aparece en la captura de pantalla que he adjuntado en el mensaje original.

Comment: Las variables `-Dcontrast.<algo>` parecen ser propias del agente que se encuentra en `contrast.jar`. ¿Estás seguro que existen dichas variables para tu nuevo agente `FortifyAgent.jar`? No es que puedas simplemente agregar una variable `-Dloquesea` y esperar que el sistema "mágicamente" lo reconozca e interprete.

Comment: La verdad es que lo he intentado de todas las formas; poniendo simplemente la línea de -javaagent, comentando todo lo demás, etc. Al final, siempre arroja los mismos errores.